# Editing docker-compose.yml with PyYAML

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pyyaml

I have a pretty standard docker-compose.yml and I need to edit the password of the database programmatically.

Since its a YAML file, I thought it would be simple to edit and dump the content.
So far I tried the PyYAML and it just mess the docker-compose file and I don't know why.

Loading and dumping the same content, it breaks the structure.

Content of the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: xxx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/xxx
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: .
  mysql:
    ports:
     - "32768:32768"
     - "3306:3306"
    container_name: xxx-mysql
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'thiswillbechangeonsetupscript'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'xxxdb'
    volumes:
     - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

This is how I'm loading and dumping the content:

```
import yaml

with open("docker-compose.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    docker_config = yaml.load(ymlfile)

with open("docker-compose.yml", 'w') as newconf:
    yaml.dump(docker_config, newconf)
```

And this is how the file is saved.

```
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: xxx-mysql
    environment: {MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxdb, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: thiswillbechangeonsetupscript}
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports: ['3306:3306']
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./database:/var/lib/mysql']
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: xxx
    depends_on: [mysql]
    ports: ['80:80']
    volumes: ['.:/xxx']
version: '2'
```

Is there any better way to do this?! What I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `default_flow_style=False` when you write the yaml:

```
import yaml

with open("docker-compose.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    docker_config = yaml.load(ymlfile)

with open("docker-compose_new.yml", 'w') as newconf:
    yaml.dump(docker_config, newconf, default_flow_style=False)
```

Then you will get the following as output which, except using alphabetic order to write the lines, is similar to your input:

```
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: xxx-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: thiswillbechangeonsetupscript
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: xxx
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - .:/xxx
version: '2'
```

Please note that, in your original `docker-compose.yaml` you are declaring the `ports` variable twice, so yaml parser will only consider the last variable. To fix that, remove the following lines:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

Then, running the write operation as explained above gives the following ouput:

```
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: xxx-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: thiswillbechangeonsetupscript
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
    - 32768:32768
    - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: xxx
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - .:/xxx
version: '2'
```

Comment: It is similar, but not the same. The port mapping "32768:32768" is missing from the dump because of the duplicate keys that PyYAML erroneously ignores.

Comment: Switched to ruamel.yaml and worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The default dump for PyYAML is to use flow style for leaf nodes ( `[....]` for sequences, `{...}` for mappings), so the minimum you should do is specify `yaml.dump(....., default_flow_style=False)`

Then the YAML specifications state that the order of the keys is not guaranteed, and what you see is that PyYAML dumps them in sorted order.

I can recommend to use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), which had the specific goal to allow this kind of round-tripping with minimal, changes compared to the input, often none at all. Including key ordering, flow vs block style, quotes on strings etc.

There is another reason to use `ruamel.yaml`: if you run this program on your input:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent(sequence=3, offset=1)

with open("docker-compose.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    data = yaml.load(ymlfile)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you'll get a **DuplicateKeyError**:

```
ruamel.yaml.constructor.DuplicateKeyError: while constructing a mapping
  in "docker-compose.yml", line 13, column 5
found duplicate key "ports" with value "[]" (original value: "[]")
  in "docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 5
```

because `ports` occurs two times as key in the mapping that is the value for the key `mysql`. This is not allowed according to the YAML specifications (the old 1.1 that PyYAML fallows and the newer 1.2), but PyYAML silently disposes of the first key-value pair, leaving port 32768 unmapped.

After deleting the last two lines from your input, the output of the program is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: xxx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - .:/xxx
    depends_on:
     - mysql
    build: .
  mysql:
    ports:
     - "32768:32768"
     - "3306:3306"
    container_name: xxx-mysql
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'thiswillbechangeonsetupscript'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'xxxdb'
    volumes:
     - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
```

which is hopefully close enough for your intended purpose.

Please note that PyYAML remove the quotes in `- "80:80"`, which is fine because `80:80` cannot be falsely interpreted as a sexagesimal, but if you do something with port 25 changing `- 80:80` to `- 25:25` is vastly different when using a YAML 1.1 parser like PyYAML (as `docker-compose` does) from `- "25:25" (the former equalling`- 1525`)

Based on this I have made a utility [`ruamel.dcw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw/0.5.0), that uses this functionality to pre-process docker compose files, allowing defaults for environment variables (in case they are not set) and a few other tricks, writes out a temporary file and then calls `docker-compose -f tmpfile`, you should use a similar technique, disposing of your temporary file after the run.